# Mock a class and a class method in python unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using python's unittest.mock to do some testing in a Django app. I want to check that a class is called, and that a method on its instance is also called.

For example, given this simplified example code:

```
# In project/app.py
def do_something():
    obj = MyClass(name='bob')
    return obj.my_method(num=10)
```

And this test to check what's happening:

```
# In tests/test_stuff.py
@patch('project.app.MyClass')
def test_it(self, my_class):
    do_something()
    my_class.assert_called_once_with(name='bob')
    my_class.my_method.assert_called_once_with(num=10)
```

The test successfully says that `my_class` is called, but says `my_class.my_method` isn't called. I know I'm missing something - mocking a method on the mocked class? - but I'm not sure what or how to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second mock assertion needs to test that you are calling `my_method` on the *instance*, not on the class itself.

Call the mock object like this,

```
my_class().my_method.assert_called_once_with(num=10)
        ^^
```

Comment: Doh! I spent so long looking into what I thought I was doing wrong with mock that I missed that silly mistake! Thanks Jared.

Answer (score 3):

A small refactoring suggestion for your unittests to help with other instance methods you might come across in your tests. Instead of mocking your class in each method, you can set this all up in the `setUp` method. That way, with the class mocked out and creating a mock object from that class, you can now simply use that object as many times as you want, testing all the methods in your class.

To help illustrate this, I put together the following example. Comments in-line:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # patch the class
        self.patcher = patch('your_module.MyClass')
        self.my_class = self.patcher.start()

        # create your mock object
        self.mock_stuff_obj = Mock()
        # When your real class is called, return value will be the mock_obj
        self.my_class.return_value = self.mock_stuff_obj

    def test_it(self):
        do_something()

        # assert your stuff here
        self.my_class.assert_called_once_with(name='bob')
        self.mock_stuff_obj.my_method.assert_called_once_with(num=10)

    # stop the patcher in the tearDown
    def tearDown(self):
        self.patcher.stop()
```

To provide some insight on how this is put together, inside the `setUp` method we will provide functionality to apply the patch across multiple methods as explained in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#applying-the-same-patch-to-every-test-method).

The patching is done in these two lines:

```
    # patch the class
    self.patcher = patch('your_module.MyClass')
    self.my_class = self.patcher.start()
```

Finally, the mock object is created here:

```
    # create your mock object
    self.mock_stuff_obj = Mock()
    self.my_class.return_value = self.mock_stuff_obj
```

Now, all your test methods can simply use `self.my_class` and `self.mock_stuff_obj` in all your calls.

Comment: Thanks idjaw. I actually started doing something a bit like this later on, but this is still very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
 my_class.my_method.assert_called_once_with(num=10)
```

will work if `my_method` is a class method.

Is it the case?

Otherwise, if `my_method` is just an normal instance method, then you will need to refactor the function `do_something` to get hold of the instance variable `obj`

e.g.

```
def do_something():
    obj = MyClass(name='bob')
    return obj, obj.my_method(num=10)

# In tests/test_stuff.py
@patch('project.app.MyClass')
def test_it(self, my_class):
    obj, _ = do_something()
    my_class.assert_called_once_with(name='bob')
    obj.my_method.assert_called_once_with(num=10)
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony. Is this different/better in some way than Jared's answer? (I'm not saying it isn't, I just don't understand enough to know!)