# Python unittest mock class and class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I feel like this may be relatively simple, but I'm pulling my hair out to get this working. I'd like to mock an entire class, and then specify the return value for one of this class's methods.

I already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585431/mock-a-class-and-a-class-method-in-python-unit-tests), at several other questions, and of course in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). I'm still unable to get this to work. Please see my simple example below.

Contents of directory `tmp`:

```
tmp
├── __init__.py
├── my_module.py
└── test_my_module.py
```

Contents of `my_module.py`:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # Do expensive operations that will be mocked in testing.
        self.a = 7

    def my_method(self):
        # For sake of simple example, always return 1.
        return 1


def create_class_call_method():
    """Create MyClass instance and call its my_method method, returning
    the result."""
    instance = MyClass()
    value = instance.my_method()
    return value
```

Contents of `test_my_module.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

from tmp import my_module


class MyClassTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_create_class_call_method(self):
        # Attempt to patch MyClass as well as specify a return_value for
        # the my_method method (spoiler: this doesn't work)
        with patch('tmp.my_module.MyClass',
                   my_method=Mock(return_value=2)):
            value = my_module.create_class_call_method()

        self.assertEqual(value, 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Results of running `test_my_module.py`:

```
2 != <MagicMock name='MyClass().my_method()' id='140234477124048'>

Expected :<MagicMock name='MyClass().my_method()' id='140234477124048'>
Actual   :2
```

Some other things I've tried:

- Rather than `..., my_method=Mock(return_value=2))` in the `patch` statement, unpack a dictionary like so: `**{'my_method.return_value': 2}`
- Nested `with patch` statements. Outer statement is simple like `with patch('tmp.my_module.MyClass'):`, inner statement attempts to patch `my_method` like so: `with patch('tmp.my_module.MyClass.my_method, return_value=2)`
- Use patch decorators instead of context managers
- Change patch statement to `with patch('tmp.my_module.MyClass') as p:` and then inside the `with` statement, try to set `p` like so: `p.evaluate = Mock(return_value=2)`

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Not your issue but you may want to make a `classmethod` via the `@classmethod` decorator and keep it inside the class. (Though it will act a little different than what you implemented). Well worded question.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse - thanks for your comment. In my real implementation, the `create_class_call_method` is slightly more complicated, and is actually used by a different class, which creates an object and calls one of its methods. So I don't think I can make it a `classmethod`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found a much better solution. In short, we need to mock out the `return_value` of the `MyClass` mock. Here's the working test code:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock, MagicMock

from tmp import my_module


class MyClassTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_create_class_call_method(self):
        # Create a mock to return for MyClass.
        m = MagicMock()
        # Patch my_method's return value.
        m.my_method = Mock(return_value=2)

        # Patch MyClass. Here, we could use autospec=True for more
        # complex classes.
        with patch('tmp.my_module.MyClass', return_value=m) as p:
            value = my_module.create_class_call_method()

        # Method should be called once.
        p.assert_called_once()
        # In the original my_method, we would get a return value of 1.
        # However, if we successfully patched it, we'll get a return
        # value of 2.
        self.assertEqual(value, 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

And the successful results:

```
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
```

Comment: What made you use `MagicMock` for the class and `Mock` for the method?

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure about the implementation of `create_class_call_method`, but try the following:

```
from unittest import mock

class MyClassTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('tmp.my_module.MyClass.my_method')
    @mock.patch('tmp.my_module.MyClass.__init__')
    def test_create_class_call_method(self, my_class_init, my_method_mock):
        my_class_init.return_value = None
        my_method.return_value = 2

        value = my_module.create_class_call_method()

        self.assertEqual(value, 2)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Will this patch all of `MyClass`, or just `MyClass.my_method` (I think the latter)? For my use case, I need `MyClass` to be mocked in its entirety (I don't want the code in its constructor to be executed), and I _also_ need to specify the return value for a call to `MyClass.my_method`

Comment: @blthayer, it will patch this specific method. I consider you should follow this approach because the purpose of unit-testing is to test a unit, so if you mock a whole class, you are probably testing more than a unit.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment, and I'm certainly testing more than a "unit." However, I'm testing a method which in reality calls several methods (including creating an object and calling a method, like what I have in `create_class_call_method`) and aggregates the results. While I have more true "unit" tests for each of these methods, I want to cement in stone (or in a unit test :) ) that this method which aggregates results is calling particular methods and correctly performing the aggregation. Hence my desire to mock the whole class, and just get a return from a method.

Comment: @blthayer, if that is the case, I strongly suggest you to use several mocks, and probably declare them as annotations from the method not using the `with` statement to avoid too much nesting. Then use the features of mocks such as `return_value` or `side_effect` to reach the state you need before calling the actual testing unit.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Would you be willing to help me with a small example of what you're describing? I did try to take a similar approach to what you're describing at first, but came up short. The thing that's tripping me up is that a `MyClass` object is instantiated, and then has a method called in the function which I'm testing. So I'm not exactly sure how I would inject a mock in there without using patch.

Comment: @blthayer, sure... so you want an example of a class mocked and changing the returned value of its methods?

Comment: Thank you - and yes, but like I said, the class is instantiated in the method under test. So I think it's slightly more nuanced. Essentially, I'd like to know how we can test `create_class_call_method` to a) assert that `MyClass.my_method` was called and that b) we can specify the return value of `MyClass.my_method` (in my real use case, that return value will be used for something else, so I need to control it).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196484/discussion-between-lmiguelvargasf-and-blthayer).

Answer (score 5):

I think the correct approach is found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53485182/1599229)

note: the below is a sketch - may not get all the details of the OP correct

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from tmp import my_module

class MyClassTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('tmp.my_module.MyClass')
    def test_create_class_call_method(self, my_class_mock):
       my_class_mock.return_value.my_method.return_value = 2
       value = my_module.create_class_call_method()
       self.assertEqual(value, 2)
```